# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() for login

Tags: php, mysqli

On my php login page i am using prepared statement but i found an `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in.....line no.63` 
All most I checked all possibility to resolve it. But i didnt find solutoin. 
And my server has mysqli and mysqlnd both are enabled. PHP version is 5.4.45 And here is my code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from user where email=? and password=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $postEmail, $postPass);
$stmt->store_result();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
$fet = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

I also tried with `$stmt->execute();` AND `$fet = $result->fetch_assoc();` AND `$fet = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)` Where is incorrect ???

Comment: bind then execute

Comment: `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: and make sure mysqlnd is available in your env

Comment: i tried it. but it gives that parameter not match.
I want to use selec * from.................

Comment: yes, mysqlnd is enabled